# Loading VC created in storyboard from VC created in code

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a situation where I need a custom container view controller created in code, but from it I want to go to views created in storyboard, so I don't have to do all the layout in code. I can make the transition to the views if I create them in code, like by for now just setting a background color.

Here's a diagram of what my situation is. The green VCs are done in storyboard, the red ones in code, and the blue ones work in code but don't load if I design in storyboard and then try to link via the identity inspector.

[image]

Here's how I get to the red Nav controller (A):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self openContainer];
}

- (void)openContainer {
    CustomContainerViewController *customContainer = [[CustomContainerViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:customContainer];
    navController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the segue from the custom controller to the detail view vontrollers 1,2, and 3: (I trimmed some code at the bottom that just relates to animation.)

```
-(IBAction)tabTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"You selected segment %ld", (long) [sender selectedSegmentIndex]);

    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:

            [self loadViewController:[[ViewController1 alloc] init] fromLeft:NO];
            break;
        case 1:
            if ([self.currentVC isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]]) {
                [self loadViewController:[[ViewController2 alloc] init] fromLeft:YES];
            } else {
            [self loadViewController:[[ViewController2 alloc] init] fromLeft:NO];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            [self loadViewController:[[ViewController3 alloc] init] fromLeft:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)loadViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
                  fromLeft:(BOOL)fromLeft
{
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    if (!self.currentVC) {
        [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
        vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        self.currentVC = vc;
        return;
    }
}
```

I tried to access the storyboard from the container view controller so I could instantiateViewControllerWithIndentifier, but since the container isn't part of the storyboard it doesn't work.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:]` to get to the storyboard, then you can use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: @pbasdf Many thanks. That worked. I put the code to instantiate all the vcs in ViewDidLoad of the custom containervc. Is that the right place or will it get called repeatedly? I see conflicting advice online.

Comment: Yes, I would use `viewDidLoad` - as far as I know, it will only be executed once.